# SQL SELECT DISTINCT for dynamic data

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-formula, filtering

Need a little help if possible:
Got data as follows , but this is filtered , the INQUIRYID column is what i am trying to work with as this is the Inquiry Number of the booking:

The last column has the number of nights in I am trying to calculate using Excel 2007.

The Column `INQ_DATE` are the booked nights for the hotel stay , in this case , this enquiry is for 2 nights. Each booking has the amount of lines on it which equals the amount of nights they are staying for.

A second booking is as follows:

```
7 lines - INQUIRYID = 9501
```

This booking is for 7 nights , which differs from the first one above of 2 nights.

In the column at the end , i need to calculate the nights , on the filtered data .

there are two tables involved :

```
BOOKING_INQUIRY
BOOKING_INQUIRY_ROOMS
Linked on : INQUIRYID
```

So far i have:

In SQL(Which works but has specified a specific INQUIRYID)

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(INQUIRYID)FROM dbo.BOOKING_INQUIRY_ROOMS
WHERE 
inquiryid = '9501'
```

This returns 7

I know i am nearly there and need to adapt the WHERE clause , to maybe a dynamic parameter , but cant for the life of me how...

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: In short, are you looking for distinct count of inquiryID? If so, you would need to use distinct inside the count. `SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT INQUIRYID)FROM dbo.BOOKING_INQUIRY_ROOMS
WHERE 
inquiryid = '9501'
`

Comment: I think he rather needs to count nights for every booking in one SELECT.

Comment: This is correct , i need to calculate all the nights in every booking , where the booking ID is different , and some booking maybe 2 nights , some 3 , some 4 etc .The amount of lines in each booking depicts the amount of nights in the Excel sheet. I am using  a filter to filter out each booking , using the INQUIRYID column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  inquiryid,
  COUNT(*) as Nights 
FROM 
  dbo.BOOKING_INQUIRY_ROOMS
GROUP BY
  inquiryid
```

Just use GROUP BY...

Comment: Thanks for your comments , I will try these today and feedback to you.

Comment: I used the group by clause and shoehorned this into my SS next to the other data in the end two columns. Great answer , cheers